# Unable to install Google USB Driver on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows

I'm trying to root my Nexus 6P, and according to [the guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928) I need to install the Google USB driver. I've tried following the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver) on the Android dev website.

I'm able to get to the point where I browse to the driver folder and click install. When I do that, Windows thinks for half a second and tells me that the best driver is already installed; "MTP USB Device" (see link below). I followed the instructions for disabling driver signature enforcement I found on SO (see link below), but still wasn't able to override the "Latest Driver" message on Windows.

I'm able to connect to the phone using ADB and Fastboot (both return serial numbers just fine). Can I use this MTP USB Driver that came with Windows and be OK? If not, how can I install the correct Google driver? Running Windows 10 v. 1607 (build 14393.693).

---

Note: My apologies for the link list at the bottom like this. I'm just trying to provide as much info as possible, but SO doesn't allow to to add more than 2 links since I don't have 10 reputation.

MTP USB Device screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/nHSql.png

SO Thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/33203839/unable-to-use-android-usb-drivers-on-windows-10

Comment: Sorry, but you are off topic on Stackoverflow: Using MTP in Windows 10 is not a programming topic.

Comment: Why you don't ask in the frum you followed the guide?